# How to print memory variable in U-boot?

Tags: linux, u-boot

i have the following lines in my U-boot environment:

```
ram_crc=10e00000
check_rd=if itest.l *$ram_crc == $crc_rd; then bootm $kernel; else run fail_h; fi
```

The comparison works. But how can i echo the contents of the memory address 10e00000?

I tried to print in the failure handler:

```
set fail_h echo $ram_crc
```

but when i print the environment i can see that it has replaced the variable with the memory address:

```
fail_h=echo 10e00000
```

How can i print the contents of the memory address?

Thanks!

Comment: For more information about using the md commands check this: http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/UBootCmdGroupMemory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For printing '*contents of the memory address 10e00000*' try:

```
 md 10e00000 1
```

or by using variable:

```
 md  ${ram_crc} 1
```

Where 1 is the wanted length of the dump.